# Jupyter does not execute code in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running Ubunutu 16.04 with Python 3.6 and I have installed Jupyter notebook, now whenever I try to run `jupyter notebook notebook` it opens up in a browser but without any button to run the code, and outputs the code as plain text.

What should I do to fix this?

[image: screenshot attached]

Comment: Please, [don't post your code/error messages as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4298200). Firstly we want to copy/paste it and secondly search engines are unable to index that information. So please make sure that any textual information is actually provided in text form.

Comment: I understand and it was not an error, it was a image just to show that how it look like where I don't see any controls to run the program. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter is made to **run** and edit noteboks (`.ipynb` files), not `.py` files.

Comment: Thank you but when I want to add a new ipynb file then its difficult! but I found that by moving to right corner on notebook page there is a button **New** from there a drop down shows from where if I select **Python3** it solves everything